# What is the meaning / significance of this Capacitor Symbol?

Tags: capacitor, schematics, symbol

In the SanKen data sheet for an Off-Line PWM Controller (found [here](http://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/str-w605xs_ds_en.pdf)) they use, in several places, a schematic symbol for an electrolytic capacitor that I haven't seen before (see C6 in the image below).

[image: Circuit Schematic]

The image was taken from Chapter 12. Reference Design of Power Supply. And from the Bill of Materials they list "C6 Electrolytic 22 μF, 50V".

What is the meaning / significance of the the three slanted lines on the capacitor symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a electrolytic capacitor.  That's a old way of drawing it not used much anymore.  They aren't trying to tell you anything special, which is confirmed by the BOM.

Answer (score 1):

It's a specific symbol used to refer to a Japanese Electrolytic capacitor, there are a few international symbols seen on older schematics, nowadays symbols tend to be more standard and universal but you still come across plenty of older drawings. When in doubt simply search Google for international or obsolete electrolytic schematic symbols - or get a page of ALL standard and obsolete equivalents. It's not obvious that it's electrolytic, only that it's polarised, I think this is why people are often confused by non-standard symbols and why some form of 'standard' was required. :)

Comment: This symbol is in common use by the Japanese suppliers I work with.

Comment: For a second there I thought you meant *"use a Japanese capacitor"*, although, that would still be good advice (Nichicon, Rubycon, Chemicon... as opposed to one from *"The Arbitrary Brand Company"*)

Comment: @Sam If in doubt use Panasonic :-)